# SOAP Web service API Key

Tags: java, web-services, soap, java-metro-framework, api-key

I am currently working on a project related to fantasy football in java and would like to expose functionality via SOAP based web service. I have noticed that some existing firms share their web service along with an API key when you registered. If a client wishes to consume the service, they need to pass in the any parameters required for the method along with the mandatory API key. I would like to introduce a similar functionality and also would like to know whether there are any good libraries for java that can be used to generate an API key for each registered user who wish to consume the web service. Appreciate if you could share any existing tutorial along with the answer. Thanks in advance.

My current tech stack:
Netbeans - ide,GlassFish,JSF,Metro and MySQL

sample reference:
http://www.xmlsoccer.com/FootballData.asmx/GetLiveScore?ApiKey=YourAPIKey

WSDL of the above sample:
www.xmlsoccer.com/FootballData.asmx?WSDL

Docs:
www.xmlsoccer.com/xmlsoccer.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what your specific question is. You ask "... whether there are any good libraries for java that can be used to generate an API key for each registered user" - there's nothing special about generating API keys, they are typically just random strings. If you are looking for a complete solution (including web-based interface for developers to sign up and get an API key), there are a few hosted solutions available, see e.g. http://blog.programmableweb.com/2011/10/19/api-service-provider-roundup/ . In general, I think you will find few resources related to SOAP and public API developer keys, since most *public* developer APIs created these days tend to be REST, with SOAP being used primarily in "closed" enterprise scenarios.